# generating string from grid values

Tags: grid, form-submit, extjs4.1

I have a form panel with two fieldsets. One fieldset set contains textfields and the other contains a grid with checkcolumns. When the user clicks the 'Create Project' button, I want a string to be generated which is displayed in the alert message. So far I have succeeded in generating a string out of the textfields. However, I have not succeeded in doing so out of the grid records (Note: I am aware that a grid is not a valid form child. Also only the modified records in the grid need to be generated into a string). Any tips on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works:

```
Ext.each(teststore.getRange(), function (rec, idx, a) {
                        var s = [],
                            data = rec.data,
                            key;

                    for (key in data) {
                        s.push('&teststore', '[', idx, '].', key, '=', data[key]);
                        }
                        alert(s.join(''));
                    });
```

Right now the alert shows one record at a time as a string. However, I want all the records in the store to be displayed in one alert message. I am still workng on that.

Comment: Here is code for all the records to be displayed in one alert message:  var s = []; Ext.each(selection, function (rec, idx, a) { var data = rec.data, key; for (key in data) { s.push('&teststore', '[', idx, '].', key, '=', data[key]); } }); alert(s.join(''));